# The function `CGCMSUtilsGetICCProfileDataWithRenderingIntent' is obsolete. Why does this solution work?

Tags: ios6

I am maintaining some code written by someone else and when I build on Xcode 4.5 and run on iOS 6 I get this run time "error"

```
<Error>: The function `CGCMSUtilsGetICCProfileDataWithRenderingIntent' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance. Please use `CGColorSpaceCopyICCProfile' instead.
```

when executing this code:

```
CGColorSpaceRef alternate   = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();               
NSString *iccProfilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sRGB Profile" ofType:@"icc"];
NSData *iccProfileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:iccProfilePath];
CGDataProviderRef iccProfile = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)iccProfileData);

const CGFloat range[] = {0,1,0,1,0,1}; // min/max of the three components
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateICCBased(3, range, iccProfile, alternate);

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, pageWidth, pageHeight, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGDataProviderRelease(iccProfile);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGColorSpaceRelease(alternate);
```

When I run on iOS 5.1 there is no error.

I have found that by making the following changes the error does not appear:

Change:

```
NSString *iccProfilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sRGB Profile" ofType:@"icc"];
NSData *iccProfileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:iccProfilePath];
CGDataProviderRef iccProfile = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)iccProfileData);
```

to:

```
char fname[]= "sRGB Profile.icc";
CGDataProviderRef iccProfile = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(fname);
```

I can't find any reference to **CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData** being deprecated. Can anyone explain the cause of the problem? It seems as though **CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData** is using **CGCMSUtilsGetICCProfileDataWithRenderingIntent** and **CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename** is using **CGColorSpaceCopyICCProfile** which suggests to me that **CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData** is deprecated. I'm not comfortable with the solution I have found because I don't understand this. Also, I hope the solution helps someone.

Comment: OK, I've found out one reason why it "works" i.e. doesn't generate an error: iccProfile in nil in the second version! I'l investigate further

Comment: ok, sorry folks. forget this one. CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename needs a full path, iccProfile was nil which is why the error disappeared. Using a full path shows the problem hasn't gone away

Answer (score 1):

So, you are attaching the sRGB color profile file to the app resources and then explicitly creating a sRGB color profile at runtime on iOS. Is that needed? This document seems to suggest that the device RGB is actually the sRGB colorspace:

[Apple WWDC color management talk](http://www.pupuweb.com/blog/wwdc-2012-session-523-practices-color-management-ken-greenebaum-luke-wallis/)

It would be nice if we could just call:

```
colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB);
```

But this does not seem to be supported on iOS either.